# c++ IPC - d3d hook and directshow capture source

Tags: c++, ipc, hook, directshow, direct3d

I'm writing an app that will basically be like Fraps, but it will push video frames as a DirectShow Capture Source. This will make it easy to stream games on websites like ustream, justin.tv, etc. I'm wondering what the best way to do the interprocess communication would be. Speed is very important. Right now I have a dll that is injected and hooks d3d to grab the frame buffer. I need a way to send that to a directshow filter. DirectShow is really confusing for me, but I've implemented CSource an CSourceStream (in another dll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed, use [shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx). Combine that with COM for normal communication and you got a standard windows IPC approach.

If you want to wrap it up with a more modern C++ style, take a look at [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)' primitives.